# Microsoft Access Report Creation

Tags: date, ms-access, grouping

I am very new to access and I am trying to create a report based on the information I have in my tables. Here is a sample of the current data that is in the table...

```
id      Date          Name       Location      Model      Count
 1      06/10/2012    William    Basement      Desktop    22
 2      06/10/2012    Doug       Top Floor     Desktop    15
 3      06/10/2012    Jane       Top Floor     Laptop     12
 4      06/11/2012    William    Basement      Desktop    29
 5      06/11/2012    Doug       Top Floor     Desktop    35
 6      06/12/2012    William    Basement      Desktop    31
 7      06/12/2012    Doug       Top Floor     Desktop    41
 8      06/12/2012    Jane       Top Floor     Laptop     24
```

Now what I am after is to create a report that will group by Month and total up the counts, taking the last count and subtracting the first one from the first day of the month that's recorded. So, my report should come out looking like this, leaving out ID as that's not necessary data for the report.

```
Date          Name       Location      Model      Count
June 2012     William    Basement      Desktop    9
June 2012     Doug       Top Floor     Desktop    26
June 2012     Jane       Top Floor     Laptop     12
```

If anyone has any ideas how i can accomplish this, keeping in mind I am very new to access, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query first and then base your report on that. Include a control that you can set to the difference between MaxOfCount and MinOfCount.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format([Date],"yyyy mm") AS Sort, 
       Format([Date],"mmm yyyy") AS [Month], 
       a.Name, a.Location, a.Model, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 [Count] 
        FROM Report b 
        WHERE a.Name=b.Name AND a.Location=b.Location AND a.Model=b.Model 
        ORDER BY [Date] DESC, Id) As MaxOfCount, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 [Count] 
        FROM Report b 
        WHERE a.Name=b.Name AND a.Location=b.Location AND a.Model=b.Model 
        ORDER BY [Date], Id) AS MinOfCount
FROM Report a
```

Comment: this looks good, but i have a question. I haven't tested it yet as i am unsure of a few things... you are referring to a.Name a.Location etc, I understand "a" would be my table, but later on you are saying "from Report b where a.name=b.name etc" what is b?

Comment: Report is the name of your table. There are two aliases, "a" and "b". You could say `FROM Report As b` or `As a`. You have two aliases because you need subqueries to get the first and last Count by date. BTW If the column names are real, you are using a lot of [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) and these are likely to cause you problems all along the way.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it out soon and report back. You have been a great help. The column names aren't exact, i just shortened them...actual ones are examples "Name" is "UsersFullName" and Model is "StationModel" and count is "ProductionCounts".

Comment: results seem to be the same...for example for 1 line in both may and june, the MaxOfCount and MinOfCount are exactly the same for all lines that happen in both may and june... "May 2012 Name: William - Maxofcount 200 - MinOfCount 134" and then "June 2012 Name: William - Maxofcount 200 - MinOfCount 134"

Comment: Your sample data provides one month only. I was a bit lost in what you wanted. If you need a more complex query, you need to provide more accurate data.

Comment: The original query provided is working fine...SELECT Format([Date],"mmm yyyy") AS [Month], Report.Name AS Name, Report.Location AS Location, Report.Model AS Model, Max([Report.Counts]) AS MaxOfCount, Min([Report.Counts]) AS MinOfCount
FROM Report
GROUP BY Format([Date],"yyyy mm"), Format([Date],"mmm yyyy"), Report.Name, Report.Location, Report.Model; I am now attempting to sort by month and then by maxofcounts, keeps asking for something when i do "ORDER BY [Month], [MaxOfCounts];" perhaps I am doing it wrong, I am used to MySQL :)